# Checking two columns duplicate in Doctrine2

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm, duplicates

I wrote an API call that extracts .json file in MainTable.

In LangTable I have 3 languages and I am extracting the json data for every language.

Json data has key and locale field to populate.

To escape duplicate there should be no duplicated key<->locale values, so that should be checked for each key.

How to check that before persisting the database?

Code below works. Now I need to add logic I mentioned.

Can anybody help?

```
    $file = file_get_contents('translation.json');
    $jsonData = json_decode($file, true);

    $findLanguage = $this->getLangTableRepository()->findAll();

    foreach ( $findLanguage as $locale) {
        foreach ($jsonData as $data) {
            $newTranslation = new MainTable();
            $newTranslation->setKey($data);
            $newTranslation->setLocale($locale->getLocale());
            $this->em->persist($newTranslation);
        }
    }

    $this->em->flush();

    dump('done!');die;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
```

UniqueEntity to add a constraint about being unique like so :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity") 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\MainBundle\Entity\EntityRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"attributeA"}, message="Attribute A already exists
 */
```

Comment: Thank you for replay. Can UniqueEntity be used if I need to check if to fields value are the same? I have key and locale columns. For example if I have key['My name'] and locale['en'] then to skip but if doesn't exist key['My name'] and locale['ru'] to add. @DylanKas

Comment: If you want you can put UniqueEntity on multiple attribute if that's what you are asking