# Skip entity that exist in database

Tags: php, symfony, if-statement, doctrine-orm, entity

I have json data that I need to import in db. 
I need to check two field values in database before persisting entity. 
If they exist to skip them without throwing an error and if not to create just the one missing.

```
        $file = file_get_contents('file.json');
        $jsonData = json_decode($file, true);

        $check = $this->getMyRepository()->findOneBy([
                'first_name' => $firstName,
                'last_name' => $lastName
            ]);

        foreach ($jsonData as $data) {

            if ($check) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $new = new MyEntity();
                $new->setFirstName($data->getFirstName());
                $new->setLastName($data->getLastName());
                $this->em->persist($new);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

The import is working but when I trigger an api it always import all values and it shouldn't as I mentioned.

Comment: Move that calling findOneBy into the foreach and $firstName $lastName replace with $data->getFirstName() and $data->getLastName()

Comment: Thank you for replay. Won't work because Call to a member function getFirsName() on string @LiTe

Comment: Let us see an example of your json file please

Comment: @develops So it can't work in setting up your entity either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the comments in the code to see what has changed and why

Basically you covert the json file to an Array, so you have to address `$data` as an array to get its values.

The code that checks if this person already exists should be inside the loop as you want to check each person as you process the set of people in the json file.

> Now we know that your JSON File is really not helping and does not really deserve the name JSON.....

Example file

```
{ "John Doe": "John Doe", "Jane Doe": "Jane Doe" }
```

The code would need to be

```
        $file = file_get_contents('file.json');
        $jsonData = json_decode($file, true);


        foreach ($jsonData as $data) {
             // Split the single field into Firstname and lastname
            $name = explode(' ', $data);

            $exists = $this->getMyRepository()->findOneBy([
                                'first_name' => $name[0],
                                'last_name' => $name[1]
                            ]);

            if ($exists) { 
                // this person already in the database
                // thats cool, just dont try and insert them again
                continue;
            } else {

                // again in here you are getting data from an array 
                // called `$data` and not an entity with getters and setters
                $new = new MyEntity();
                $new->setFirstName($name[0]);
                $new->setLastName($name[1]);
                $this->em->persist($new);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

> **Big Warning** This code relies on the JSON Data file ALWAYS having a first name and a lastname seperated by a space.  ***THIS IS A VERY A DANGEROUS THING TO RELY UPON***
>
> You should really go back to the person that created this JSON file and ask then to do it properly!!!

Comment: Thank you so much but my problem is that in my json I have just the list of names like array:97 [
  "John Doe" => "John Doe"
  "Jane Doe" => "Jane Doe" ] @RiggsFolly

Comment: Please can you show us a little sample of the real json file

Comment: This is the part of my json file that I presented in comment above. @RiggsFolly

Comment: {
  "John Doe": "John Doe",
  "Jane Doe": "Jane Doe" } sorry, i copied dumped results.  @RiggsFolly

Comment: Do you have any control over the creation of that file. Because that is a pretty awful json data structure?

Comment: That is the file that I received. So I am afraid not. Is there any solution for this? @RiggsFolly

Comment: @develops In your question you said that importing works except for the duplicate filter.  If your json file is really as you posted in the comments then your importing cannot be working and should be tossing "unknown index" type errors.

Comment: I am setting just setName(), not firstName, lastName. That is second part. And the importing works fine. Just when I am triggering again it imports all names again. That is the problem. And I want to check if there are already in a database. I changed all the logic so I can work it out. Take a look of my real code here. Thank you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340135/checking-two-columns-duplicate-in-doctrine2/56340868?noredirect=1#comment99287280_56340868 @ Cerad @RiggsFolly